# Are executable files virtual addresses shown by disassemblers definitive?

Tags: c, assembly, disassembly, virtual-memory, address-space

I'm on a macOS x86_64 system.

I have this little C program in a file named test.c :

```
void fx(){

   int y = 20;
   y++;
   
}

int main(){
     
    
    int x = 10;
    x++;
    fx();
    
}
```

If I compile this with "clang test.c -o test" and then use "otool -tV test" I get :

```
(__TEXT,__text) section
_fx:
0000000100003f70        pushq   %rbp
0000000100003f71        movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100003f74        movl    $0x14, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000100003f7b        movl    -0x4(%rbp), %eax
0000000100003f7e        addl    $0x1, %eax
0000000100003f81        movl    %eax, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000100003f84        popq    %rbp
0000000100003f85        retq
0000000100003f86        nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
_main:
0000000100003f90        pushq   %rbp
0000000100003f91        movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100003f94        subq    $0x10, %rsp
0000000100003f98        movl    $0xa, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000100003f9f        movl    -0x4(%rbp), %eax
0000000100003fa2        addl    $0x1, %eax
0000000100003fa5        movl    %eax, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000100003fa8        callq   _fx
0000000100003fad        xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000100003faf        addq    $0x10, %rsp
0000000100003fb3        popq    %rbp
0000000100003fb4        retq
```

My questions :

1. Are the virtual addresses shown by the disassembler definitive or they ( could ) change ?
2. Do these addresses correspond to the addresses that we would get if we were to take addresses for example by using printf in run time ?
3. If they are not definitive virtual addresses, why adding another layer of complexity behind the virtual-physical mechanism so that it becomes something like virtual to virtual to physical ?

Comment: See [ASLR](https://www.techtarget.com/searchsecurity/definition/address-space-layout-randomization-ASLR#:~:text=Address%20space%20layout%20randomization%20(ASLR)%20is%20a%20memory%2Dprotection,executables%20are%20loaded%20into%20memory.)